# Spring Boot Actuator GC Metrics

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, java-memory-model

I am using spring boot. To monitor the JVM Memory , I am using the /metrics endpoint for Spring Boot Actuator.

I am unable to understand what actually does the keys represent:

```
"gc.copy.count": 1933,
"gc.copy.time": 35972,
"gc.marksweepcompact.count": 12,
"gc.marksweepcompact.time": 7515,
```

Can someone tell me what exactly they are?

Is CMS(Concurrent Mark Sweep) and MarkSweepCompact same?
Also should I use CMS(Concurrent Mark Sweep)? or which GC algo should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Copy,MarkSweepCompact and ConcurrentMarkSweep are differents JVM Collectors.

You can find a description of these collectors here: http://www.fasterj.com/articles/oraclecollectors1.shtml

> All of the garbage collection algorithms except ConcurrentMarkSweep
>   are stop-the-world, i.e. they stop all application threads while they
>   operate - the stop is known as 'pause' time. The ConcurrentMarkSweep
>   tries to do most of it's work in the background and minimize the pause
>   time, but it also has a stop-the-world phase and can fail into the
>   MarkSweepCompact which is fully stop-the-world. (The G1 collector has
>   a concurrent phase but is currently mostly stop-the-world).